# collect all expected input variables from terraform configuration

Tags: terraform

I am working on a project that interacts with the users through web UI. It executes commands over terraform configurations. To make the UI more user-friendly I would like to list all the expected input variable, so the customer to know what they need to provide in order the execution to go through.

What I am looking for is hopefully without the need of making my own parser of terraform configuration I to be able to collect all input variables with their type and default value.

If that is not possible, any other viable option is appreciated.

Comment: What language are you using? There are a few parsers of HCL you can use including things like [pyhcl](https://github.com/virtuald/pyhcl), [rhcl](https://github.com/winebarrel/rhcl) and [hcl4j](https://github.com/bertramdev/hcl4j)

Comment: I use java, thank you I will try hcl4j